# Filter Embedded Documents that match a condition in MongoEngine, Django, GraphQl

Tags: python-3.x, django, graphql, mongoengine

### Document Structure

#### Data

```
class Data(EmbeddedDocument):
    v = FloatField()
    q = StringField()
    co2 = FloatField()
    price = FloatField()
    ts = DateTimeField()
```

#### Meters Data

```
class MetersData(DynamicDocument):
    meta = {'collection': 'dk_heating'}
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    ident = StringField()
    meteringPointId = StringField()
    customer = StringField()
    cvr = StringField()
    type = StringField()
    unit = StringField()
    address = StringField()
    period = EmbeddedDocumentField(Period)
    hourly_data = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Data), db_field='data')
    daily_data = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Data))
    monthly_data = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Data))
    # monthly_data = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Data)
    yearly_data = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Data))
```

I am using this Query.

### Query

```
MetersData.objects.filter(address=address, customer=customer).fields(
                monthly_data={"$elemMatch": {"q": "E"}},
                address=1, customer=1, cvr=1, ident=1, meteringPointId=1, type=1, unit=1, period=1)
```

It returns me only the first matching element. I have read the documentation and it reads that $elemMatch is supposed to return only the first matching result. But in my case, I need all the matching results.

### Result of the Query

[image: Query Result]

I have searched everywhere but I am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using MongoDB pipelines.

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': {'meteringPointId': {'$in': [1,2,3]}}
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'data': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$data',
                    'as': 'data',
                    'cond': {
                        '$and': [
                            {'$gte': [f'$data.ts', from_date]},
                            {'$lt': [f'$data.ts', to_date]}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).